# Engine to render different types of graphic objects

Tags: c++, graphics, rendering

I'm trying to write a class (some sort of graphics engine) basically it's purpose is to render ANYTHING that I pass into it. In most tutorials I've seen, objects draw themselves. I'm not sure if that's how things are supposed to work. I've been searching the internet trying to come up with different ways to handle this problem, I've been reviewing function templates and class templates over and over again (which sounds like the solution I could be looking for) but when I try using templates, it just seems messy to me (possibly because I don't fully understand how to use them) and then I'll feel like taking the template class down, then I'll give it a second try but then I just take it down again, I'm not sure if that's the way to go but it might be. Originally it was tiled-based only (including a movable player on screen along with a camera system), but now I've trying to code up a tile map editor which has things such as tool bars, lists, text, possibly even primitives on screen in the future, etc. and I'm wondering how I will draw all those elements onto the screen with a certain procedure (the procedure isn't important right now, I'll find that out later). If any of you were going to write a graphics engine class, how would you have it distinguish different types of graphic objects from one another, such as a primitive not being drawn as a sprite or a sphere primitive not being drawn as a triangle primitive, etc.? Any help would be appreciated. :)

This is the header for it, it's not functional right now because I've been doing some editing on it, Just ignore the part where I'm using the "new" keyword, I'm still learning that, but I hope this gives an idea for what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
//graphicsEngine.h

#pragma once
#include<allegro5\allegro.h>
#include<allegro5\allegro_image.h>
#include<allegro5\allegro_primitives.h>

template <class graphicObjectData>
class graphicsEngine
{
public:

    static graphicObjectData graphicObject[];
    static int numObjects;

    static void setup()
    {
        al_init_image_addon();
        al_init_primitives_addon();
        graphicObject = new graphicObjectData [1]; //ignore this line
    }

    template <class graphicObjectData> static void registerObject(graphicObjectData &newGraphicObject) //I'm trying to use a template function to take any type of graphic object
    {
        graphicObject[numObjects] = &newObject; 
        numObjects++;
    }

    static void process() //This is the main process where EVERYTHING is supposed be drawn
    {
        int i;
        al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));
        for (i=0;i<numObjects;i++) drawObject(graphicObject[i]);
        al_flip_display();
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a huge fan of templates, but you may find in this case that they are cumbersome (though not necessarily the wrong answer).  Since it appears you may be wanting diverse object types in your drawing container, inheritance may actually be a stronger solution.

You will want a base type which provides an abstract interface for drawing.  All this class needs is some function which provides a mechanism for the actual draw process.  It does not actually care how drawing occurs, what's important is that the deriving class knows how to draw itself (if you want to separate your drawing and your objects, keep reading and I will try to explain a way to accomplish this):

```
class Drawable {
public: 
    // This is our interface for drawing.  Simply, we just need 
    // something to instruct our base class to draw something.
    // Note: this method is pure virtual so that is must be 
    // overriden by a deriving class.
    virtual void draw()  = 0;

    // In addition, we need to also give this class a default virtual 
    // destructor in case the deriving class needs to clean itself up.
    virtual ~Drawable() { /* The deriving class might want to fill this in */ }
};
```

From here, you would simply write new classes which inherit from the Drawable class and provide the necessary draw() override.

```
class Circle : public Drawable {
public:

    void draw() { 
        // Do whatever you need to make this render a circle.
    }

    ~Circle() { /* Do cleanup code */ }
};

class Tetrahedron : public Drawable {
public:
    void draw() { 
        // Do whatever you need to make this render a tetrahedron.
    }

    ~Tetrahedron() { /* Do cleanup code */ }

};

class DrawableText : public Drawable {
public:
    std::string _text;

    // Just to illustrate that the state of the deriving class 
    // could be variable and even dependent on other classes:
    DrawableText(std::string text) : _text(text) {}

    void draw() { 
        // Yet another override of the Drawable::draw function. 
    }

    ~DrawableText() { 
        // Cleanup here again - in this case, _text will clean itself 
        // up so nothing to do here.  You could even omit this since
        // Drawable provides a default destructor.
    }

};
```

Now, to link all these objects together, you could simply place them in a container of your choosing which accepts references or pointers (or in C++11 and greater, unique_ptr, shared_ptr and friends).  Setup whatever draw context you need and loop through all the contents of the container calling draw().

```
void do_drawing() {

    // This works, but consider checking out unique_ptr and shared_ptr for safer 
    // memory management
    std::vector<Drawable*> drawable_objects;
    drawable_objects.push_back(new Circle);
    drawable_objects.push_back(new Tetrahedron);
    drawable_objects.push_back(new DrawableText("Hello, Drawing Program!"));

    // Loop through and draw our circle, tetrahedron and text.
    for (auto drawable_object : drawable_objects) {
        drawable_object->draw();
    }

    // Remember to clean up the allocations in drawable_objects!
}
```

If you would like to provide state information to your drawing mechanism, you can require that as a parameter in the draw() routine of the Drawable base class:

```
class Drawable {
public: 
    // Now takes parameters which hold program state
    virtual void draw(DrawContext& draw_context, WorldData& world_data)  = 0;

    virtual ~Drawable() { /* The deriving class might want to fill this in */ }
};
```

The deriving classes Circle, Tetrahedron and DrawableText would, of course, need their draw() signatures updated to take the new program state, but this will allow you to do all of your low-level drawing through an object which is designed for graphics drawing instead of burdening the main class with this functionality.  What state you provide is solely up to you and your design.  It's pretty flexible.

---

**BIG UPDATE - Another Way to Do It Using Composition**

I've been giving it careful thought, and decided to share what I've been up to.  What I wrote above has worked for me in the past, but this time around I've decided to go a different route with my engine and forego a scene graph entirely.  I'm not sure I can recommend this way of doing things as it can make things complicated, but it also opens the doors to a tremendous amount of flexibility.  Effectively, I have written lower-level objects such as VertexBuffer, Effect, Texture etc. which allow me to compose objects in any way I want.  I am using templates this time around more than inheritance (though intheritance is still necessary for providing implementations for the VertexBuffers, Textures, etc.).

The reason I bring this up is because you were talking about getting a larger degree of seperation.  Using a system such as I described, I could build a world object like this:

```
class World {

public:

    WorldGeometry geometry; // Would hold triangle data.
    WorldOccluder occluder; // Runs occlusion tests against
                            // the geometry and flags what's visible and 
                            // what is not.
    WorldCollider collider; // Handles all routines for collision detections.
    WorldDrawer drawer;     // Draws the world geometry.

    void process_and_draw();// Optionally calls everything in necessary
                            // order.
};
```

Here, i would have multiple objects which focus on a single aspect of my engine's processing.  WorldGeometry would store all polygon details about this particular world object.  WorldOccluder would do checks against the camera and geometry to see which patches of the world are actually visible.  WorldCollider would process collission detection against any world objects (omitted for brevity).  Finally, WorldDrawer would actually be responsible for the drawing of the world and maintain the VertexBuffer and other lower-level drawing objects as needed.

As you can see, this works a little more closely to what you originally asked as the geometry is actually not used only for rendering.  It's more data on the polygons of the world but can be fed to WorldGeometry and WorldOccluder which don't do any drawing whatsoever.  In fact, the World class only exists to group these similar classes together, but the WorldDrawer may not be dependent on a World object.  Instead, it may need a WorldGeometry object or even a list of Triangles.  Basically, your program structure becomes highly flexible and dependencies begin to disappear since objects do not inherit often or at all and only request what they absolutely require to function.  Case in point:

```
class WorldOccluder {
public:

    // I do not need anything more than a WorldGeometry reference here //
    WorldOccluder(WorldGeometry& geometry) : _geometry(geometry)

    // At this point, all I need to function is the position of the camera //
    WorldOccluderResult check_occlusion(const Float3& camera) {
        // Do all of the world occlusion checks based on the passed 
        // geometry and then return a WorldOccluderResult
        // Which hypothetically could contain lists for visible and occluded
        // geometry
    }

private:
    WorldGeometry& _geometry;
};
```

I chose the WorldOccluder as an example because I've spent the better part of the day working on something like this for my engine and have used a class hierarchy much like above.  I've got boxes in 3D space changing colors based on if they should be seen or not.  My classes are very succinct and easy to follow, and my entire project hierarchy is easy to follow (I think it is anyway). So this seems to work just fine!  I love being on vacation!

Final note:  I mentioned templates but didn't explain them.  If I have an object that does processing around drawing, a template works really well for this.  It avoids dependencies (such as through inheritence) while still giving a great degree of flexibility.  Additionally, templates can be optimized by the compiler by inlining code and avoiding virtual-style calls (if the compiler can deduce such optimizations):

```
template <typename TEffect, TDrawable>
void draw(TEffect& effect, TDrawable& drawable, const Matrix& world, const Matrix& view, const Matrix& projection) {

    // Setup effect matrices - our effect template 
    // must provide these function signatures
    effect.world(world);
    effect.view(view);
    effect.projection(projection);

    // Do some drawing! 
    // (NOTE: could use some RAII stuff here in case drawable throws).
    effect.begin();
    for (int pass = 0; pass < effect.pass_count(); pass++) {
        effect.begin_pass(pass);
        drawable.draw();    // Once again, TDrawable objects must provide this signature
        effect.end_pass(pass);
    }
    effect.end();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it totally makes sense to the way I would normally render graphics and is the way I see some others do it but in some cases I hear that the objects SHOULDN'T need to worry about anything that has to do with drawing and that it is the entire responsibility of the graphics engine figure out how to draw the objects instead based on the given data like vectors, size, and color. Is this the way professional programmers do it?

Comment: I'm actually not sure how the pros would do it, but I wouldn't be surprised if it was similar. I've actually been working on my own engine, and in the past, this is the way that I've dealt with it. However, this time around I've been doing things differently and not even including a scene graph.  That may sound odd, but I do it to keep things flexible.  It does make writing the program harder though, as there's no universal drawing system in place. Objects are abstracted down to things like VertexBuffer, Effect, Texture, and I compose other types out of those.  I'll update my answer with info.

Comment: Enjoy the vacation! I'm suprised you're actually doing 3D! I mainly haven't started 3D yet besides trying to implement sprite z-order like top-down rpgs do it, there was one time I had a drawn a cube composed of lines and vertices, but I had no idea how I would have all sorts of 3D everywhere. However now, I have something to look back to for ideas.

Comment: Although you have offered great advice and I'll use most of it, I believe I would be better off to just split up my graphics engine into two or more classes; one built for my tile editor interface graphics (i.e: class editorInterface) and probably another class worldDrawer for the world as you suggest. I figure that having separate graphics engines would be more realistic so  when I call them, they would directly be able to draw what they're built for, without having the mix-up between different datatypes.

Comment: You know your engine better than I do, so do what works best.  I'm glad I could help spark some ideas! :)

Answer (score 0):

My technique might really suck, but I do it like this.

```
class entity {
public:
    virtual void render() {}
};

vector<entity> entities;

void render() {
    for(auto c : entities) {
        c->render();
    }
}
```

Then I can do stuff like this:

```
class cubeEntity : public entity {
public:
    virtual void render() override {
        drawCube();
    }
};

class triangleEntity : public entity {
public:
    virtual void render() override {
        drawTriangle();
    }
};
```

And to use it:

```
entities.push_back(new cubeEntity());
entities.push_back(new triangleEntity());
```

People say that it's bad to use dynamic inheritance. They're a lot smarter than me, but this approach has been working fine for a while. Make sure to make all your destructors virtual!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your way is very understandable, but I'm not sure if I should do it that way or I should pass all of the data of the "entities" to a class (i.e. the graphics engine class) that can use all of the data to do the drawing instead. Is this the way most programmers do it?

Comment: @Blahblahblah I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

The way the SFML graphics library draws objects (and the way I think is most manageable) is to have all drawable objects inherit from a 'Drawable' class (like the one in David Peterson's answer), which can then be passed to the graphics engine in order to be drawn.

To draw objects, I'd have:

**A Base class:**

```
class Drawable 
{
    int XPosition;
    int YPosition;
    int PixelData[100][100]; //Or whatever storage system you're using
}
```

This can be used to contain information common to all drawable classes (like position, and some form of data storage).

**Derived Subclasses:**

```
class Triangle : public Drawable
{
    Triangle() {} //overloaded constructors, additional variables etc
    int indigenous_to_triangle;
}
```

Because each subclass is largely unique, you can use this method to create anything from sprites to graphical-primitives.

Each of these derived classes can then be passed to the engine by reference with

**A 'Draw' function referencing the Base class:**

```
void GraphicsEngine::draw(const Drawable& _object);
```

Using this method, a template is no longer necessary. Unfortunately your current graphicObjectData array wouldn't work, because derived classes would be 'sliced' in order to fit in it. However, creating a list or vector of 'const Drawable*' pointers (or preferably, smart pointers) would work just as well for keeping tabs on all your objects, though the actual objects would have to be stored elsewhere.

You could use something like this to draw everything using a vector of pointers (I tried to preserve your function and variable names):

```
std::vector<const Drawable*> graphicObject; //Smart pointers would be better here

static void process()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < graphicObject.size(); ++i) 
        draw(graphicObject[i]);
}
```

You'd just have to make sure you added each object to the list as it was created. 
If you were clever about it, you could even do this in the construction and destruction:

```
class Drawable; //So the compiler doesn't throw an error

std::vector<const Drawable*> graphicObject;

class Drawable
{
    Triangle() {} //overloaded constructors, additional variables etc
    int indigenous_to_triangle;

    std::vector<const Drawable*>::iterator itPos; 

    Drawable() {
        graphicObject.push_back(this);
        itPos = graphicObject.end() - 1;
    }

    ~Drawable() {
        graphicObject.erase(itPos);
    }
}
```

Now you can just create objects and they'll be drawn automatically when process() is called! And they'll even be removed from the list once they're destroyed!

All the above ideas have served me well in the past, so I hope I've helped you out, or at least given you something to think about.

Comment: I appreciate all of the answers here, they are very thorough. I'll keep them in mind and see what I can do. :)